# What does Git (master|REBASE 1/1) mean? How do I get rid of it?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, rebase

I'm kind of a [git](/questions/tagged/git) beginner and I was attempting to roll back to a previous commit. But I accidentally just rolled back the commit (I was using the Windows GUI). Anyway, after some weird pushing, merging, and other confusing stuff I didn't quite understand, I finally got my files the way I wanted them. The only weird thing is in the shell now it says:

> (master|REBASE 1/1)

It used to just say `master`, so what happened? What does this mean? And how do I get it back to how it was?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You are stuck in the middle of a rebase.

If you have merged/solved conflicts for all the paths:
use `git add .` to commit resolved items.
use `git rebase --continue` to complete the process.

Or use `git rebase --abort` to exit the rebase process without any risk.

Comment: So what do the number 1 | 1 mean?

Comment: If I recall correctly, when rebasing interactively, one might have to resolve multiple merge conflicts. 1/1 means one of total one merges. I guess the same is true when applying multiple patches etc.

Answer (score 12):

If `git rebase --continue | --skip | --abort` still do not work:

You might try to **discard your local commit** one by one, then use `git status` to make sure your local commit are up-to-date with remote branch.

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

NOTE: `git reset --hard` will **discard your work**, use it only if you know what you are doing!!

Answer (score 4):

Abort the rebase and take pull again

```
git rebase --continue 
git rebase --abort
```

Answer (score 3):

If there are no unsaved changes in your directory , run the following commands

1. This will reset your current branch to remote repo

   git reset --hard origin/branch e.g. git reset --hard origin/master
2. Delete the folder -
   repo\git.git\rebase-apply

Answer (score 0):

Delete below folder which is within the working repo/git
.git\rebase-merge